# Are the geometry generated by math functions in blender faster in any way compared to other modelling methods?

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view, mathematics

As the question says, is an object generated via the blender math function faster in any way than using other modelling methods, especially poly modelling? does it cause faster rendering, view-port navigation or any other speed advantage?

Comment: Short answer AFAIK No.

Comment: Mathematical functions are just another tool in Blender and other 3D programs.  3D does not live on Mathematical functions alone, but with other tools.  Most people are not going to have much success in typical 3D presentations which include organic characters by using only mathematical functions such as trig functions and polynomials. We are excluding the degenerate identity function.  Of course the 3D textures are successful and are not organic characters.    Your question does not provide any explanation as to why you think you need to be so focused on mathematical functions.

Comment: What is the time duration of your experience with Blender or other 3D programs?  Example response .. 1 month, 6 months, 1 year.